# What does a double exclamation mark (!!) in Fsharp / FAKE?

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I've come across the following code and can not understand what operation the double exclamation marks provide. This code-snipet is from a FAKE script used in a CICD system. [Microsoft's Symbol and Operator Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/) does not list this operator, nor can I find it in [FAKE's API Reference](http://fake.build/apidocs).

```
  !! (projectPackagePath + "/*.zip")
    |> Seq.iter(fun path ->
      trace ("Removing " + path)
      ShellExec tfCommand ("delete " + path + " /noprompt")
```

Another example of usage

```
let buildLabelFiles = 
    !!(labelPath @@ "*.txt")
```

Comment: Your IDE should show the type signature and documentation string of operators that you hover over, just like with normal functions, because most of them are just functions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `!!` operator takes a file pattern and returns a collection of files matching the pattern.

For example, if you want to print all text files in the current folder, you can write:

```
for file in !! "*.txt" do
  printfn "%s" file
```

If you look at [the operator definition](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/2138945/src/app/Fake.IO.FileSystem/GlobbingFileSystem.fs#L216) in the source code, you can see that it is just an alias for creating a `IGlobbingPattern` value (see the [type definition](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/2138945/src/app/Fake.IO.FileSystem/GlobbingFileSystem.fs#L5)) that includes files given by the specified pattern. The `IGlobbingPattern` type implements `IEnumerable`, so you can iterate over the files, but you can do a couple of other things with `IGlobbingPattern` such as combining two file sets using `++` or removing some files from a file set using `--`.